# $\mathbb{G}_a$ has no nontrivial characters

Tags: algebraic-groups

As a character of an algebraic group is defined to be any morphism (of algebraic groups) from this group to $\mathbb{G}_m$, how to prove:

> $\mathbb{G}_a$ has no nontrivial characters.

If I take the ground field $K=\mathbb{C}$, and define a map $\phi: \mathbb{G}_a \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$, $a+bi \mapsto $exp$(a+bi)$, why isn't $\phi$ a character of $\mathbb{G}_a$? (Why isn't it a morphism of algebraic groups?)

Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly is $\mathbb{G_m}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to establish that there is no nontrivial homomorphism of algebraic groups from $\mathbb{G}_a$ to $\mathbb{G}_m$ is via the **Jordan decomposition**: every element $x$ in a linear algebraic group may uniquely be written as the product of a **semisimple element** $x_s$ and a **unipotent element** $x_u$, and this decomposition is preserved by homomorphisms of algebraic groups.  See for instance Theorem 6 of [these notes of Ryan Reich](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ryanr/algebraic_groups/2010-07-04%28lecture-1%29.pdf).

Now we can realize $\mathbb{G}_a$ as the subgroup of matrices $\{ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] , \ a \in K \}$,

which shows that every element of $\mathbb{G}_a$ is unipotent.  On the other hand, every element of $\mathbb{G}_m$ is semisimple.  Since an element which is both unipotent and semisimple is the identity, the only homomorphism from $\mathbb{G}_a$ to $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the trivial one.

As for your example with the exponential map: that's not an algebraic function!  Remember that in dealing with homomorphisms of algebraic groups, we restrict to maps which are locally given by polynomials.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is really detailed and impressing! Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in [this answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4062/can-hom-gpg-h-fail-to-be-representable-for-affine-algebraic-groups/4105#4105) from MO. Over a base ring $R$ which contains $\mathbb{Q}$, I show that the hom's from $\mathbb{G}_a$ to $\mathbb{G}_m$ are in canonical bijection with the nilpotent elements of $R$. In particular, if $R$ is itself a field, then the only nilpotent is $0$, giving the trivial hom.

Comment: I am really very very lucky to see admirable and helpful teachers here. Thank you very much, Mr Speyer. This answer gives me a deeper look into this question.

Answer (score 3):

Since these are affine algebraic groups, there is an equivalent ring-theoretic statement.  Namely, a character over a commutative ring $R$ is an $R$-Hopf algebra map from $R[x,x^{-1}]$ to $R[y]$, where the comultiplication is $x \mapsto x \otimes x$ on the left and $y \mapsto y \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes y$ on the right.

To be an $R$-algebra map, $x$ has to go to an invertible element of $R[y]$.  We will write it as $f(y) = \sum_{i=0}^n r_i y^i$, where $r_0 \in R^\times$.  Taking tensor square is a functor on algebras, so we get a map 
$$R[x,x^{-1}] \otimes_R R[x,x^{-1}] \to R[y] \otimes_R R[y] = R[y,z]$$
that in particular yields the assignment:
$$x \otimes x \mapsto f(y) f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^n r_j r_k y^j z^k.$$
To have a Hopf algebra map, it is necessary and sufficient that this be equal to the image of $f(y)$ under the comultiplication map, which is $$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j} r_i y^j z^{i-j}.$$
Comparing the coefficients of $y^j z^k$ yields the system of equations $r_jr_k = \binom{j+k}{j} r_{j+k}$, where $r_m = 0$ for $m > n$.

We find that $r_0 = 1$ (since $r_0$ is an invertible idempotent), and all $r_i$ for $i \geq 1$ are nilpotent.  Since the complex numbers have no nonzero nilpotents, all characters defined over $\mathbb{C}$ are trivial.

---

A little more work shows that there is a functor from schemes to sets that takes the spectrum of a ring $R$ to the character group of the additive group over $R$.  This functor is formally represented by the multiplicative formal group $\widehat{\mathbb{G}_m}$, whose reduced subscheme is $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$.  This is an example of Cartier duality where one has to allow formal schemes to take duals of commutative affine groups.

Regarding the exponential function, it does not yield a map from $R[x,x^{-1}]$ to $R[y]$, but in characteristic zero, there is a formal exponential map to the completion $R[[y]]$, which is the coordinate ring of the formal additive group $\widehat{\mathbb{G}_a}$.  This is given by sending $x$ to $\exp(y) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{y^i}{i!}$, and it is straightforward to check that the assignment $r_i = 1/i!$ satisfies the system of equations $r_j r_k = \binom{j+k}{j} r_{j+k}$.  In positive characteristic, you can't divide by $i!$, but there is a formal exponential to a formal divided power series algebra, which yields a sort of PD-additive group.  In other words, the exponential *does* yield a homomorphism when restricted to an infinitesimal neighborhood of the identity, but that homomorphism cannot be extended to a homomorphism (in group schemes) on the whole additive group.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a deeper insight into this quesiton. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If ${\Bbb G}_a$ had a non-trivial character, then there would be a systematic (in fact, *functorial*) way to produce invertible elements in any ring $R$ (or maybe in any $R_0$-algebra, where $R_0$ is the ring of definition of the character) from its additive structure.

This would be quite strange........

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand why I am wrong.